# Prevent "Target Unreachable" when entity is null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an focused person object in my bean. Some attributes of this focused person are connected with primefaces elements in the view.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="eyeColorSelection"
    value="#{bean.focusedPerson.eyeColor}" disabled="#{bean.noPersonFocused}">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{bean.eyeColorsToSelect}"
        var="eyeColor" itemLabel="#{eyeColor.i18nLabel}"
        itemValue="#{eyeColor}" />
    <f:ajax
        listener="#{bean.eyeColorSelectionChanged}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

As expected I got the following exception, if no person is focused (focusedPerson = null).

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'focusedPerson' returned null
```

But how can I handle this? My first idea was to not render the selectOneMenu, if no person is focused, but this is not what I want. The selectOneMenu should always be visible.

Bean code:

```
private Person focusedPerson

public Person getFocusedPerson() {
    return this.focusedPerson;
}

public EyeColor[] getEyeColorsToSelect() {
    return EyeColor.values();
}

public boolean isNoPersonFocused() {
    return this.focusedPerson == null;
}
```

Comment: Provide your Bean Code.

Comment: You mean, you actually want to disable the `<p:selectOneMenu>` itself when there's no `#{bean.focusedPerson}`? Why is the `disabled` attribute then on `<f:selectItems>` instead of `<p:selectOneMenu>`?

Comment: @BalusC Sorry disabled attribute should be in selectOneMenu. Copy/Paste mistake

Comment: I want to suggest something .. when there is no person focused you may initialize the person object in it's getter method `if (person == nulll ) person  = new  Person()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would very simply use two selectOneMenu components, mutually exclusive

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="eyeColorSelection" value="" 
    rendered="#{bean.noPersonFocused}" disabled="true" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="eyeColorSelection" value="#{bean.focusedPerson.eyeColor}" 
    rendered="#{not bean.noPersonFocused}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{bean.eyeColorsToSelect}" var="eyeColor" 
      itemLabel="#{eyeColor.i18nLabel}" itemValue="#{eyeColor}" />
      <f:ajax listener="#{bean.eyeColorSelectionChanged}" /> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

No way around it, if the object is null, you can't target its attributes.

I would use the `rendered` approach, but with an addition of output label that would print an appropriate message if `focusedPerson` is null (it would render only if `focusedPerson` is null).

Another common approach (but this depends on the use case) is to keep the value of `p:selectOneMenu` in a separate bean attribute, and set it to `focusedPerson` in a separate action (save, update, or anything else).

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="eyeColorSelection"
    value="#{bean.eyeColor}">
...
```

```
public void save() {
    ...
    if (getFocusedPerson() != null) {
        getFocusedPerson().setEyeColor(getEyeColor());
    }
    ...
}
```